# PhantomJS button click two times on page

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm using phantomJS to gather some information from website. There is some button which needs to be clicked two times, but i can't accomplish that with evaluate() function

```
page.open("https://www.windy.com/?nems,975h,45.265,20.270,8,m:eUCagJb", function (status) {
if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to open url');
    phantom.exit();
} else {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };
        page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 1024, height: 768 };
        var script1 = "function(){ document.getElementById('legend').children[0].click(); }";
        page.evaluate(script1)
        var script2 = "function(){ document.getElementById('legend').children[0].click(); return document.getElementsByTagName('big')[0].innerText;}";
        value = page.evaluate(script2); 

        console.log(value);
        page.render('windy.png')
        phantom.exit();
    }, 7000);  
}});
```

how can be this accomplished?

Comment: double check your code above. the variable `script3` is not defined

Comment: @GianfrancoP. thanks, it's changed to script2

Comment: Does the code return an element with `document.getElementsByTagName('big')` ? I'm not very familiar with phantomjs. Maybe since is headless it renders differently than a full browser?
Does it the debugging help in anyway? Alternatively you could try `puppeteer` instead

Comment: @GianfrancoP.it returns value which is shown, when it's clicked just one time

Comment: @GianfrancoP. thanks for puppeteer it's looks awesome!